# How to get value from an sql field to a label in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm still quite new to c# so this is probably quite silly but I want to be able to show a single value (tuition_fee) from a field field from a table in SQL in a label in c# dependent on the "tuition_code" that has been entered.. (studenttuition_code) is the tuition code that is compared to in SQL)

> Here is my code so far:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
{
   con.Open();
   string sqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT tuition_fee FROM Tuition WHERE tuition_code = '{0}'", studenttuition_code);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
     lblAmount.Text = dr.GetValue; 
   }
   con.Close(); 
}
```

> This is what I have in SQL for the Tuition Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tuition
(
    tuition_code VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
    tuition_instrument VARCHAR (3) NOT NULL,
    tuition_lessonno INT NOT NULL,
    tuition_roomcode VARCHAR (3) NOT NULL,
    tutor_id VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    tuition_fee DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tuition PRIMARY KEY (tuition_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tuitionroomcode FOREIGN KEY (tuition_roomcode) REFERENCES Room(room_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tutorfortuiton FOREIGN KEY (tutor_id) REFERENCES Tutor(tutor_id)
)
```

Comment: if you have `string.Format` function you do not need to wrap the `{ }` around single single quotes.. remove the single quotes also what happens when you execute the code / run this via debugging..?

Comment: use parameterization; replace `'{0}'` with `@tuitionCode` and then do `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuitionCode", studenttuition_code);` before you execute the query. This is to protect from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parameterization in your querying. This makes your query safe by avoiding SQL injection and it also makes formatting easier because you don't have to worry about using single quotes and all that jazz.

You only need to do dr.Read() once unless your SQL gets more than one row (which it probably should not).
You should also use `using` on each of those SQL objects because they all implement IDisposable.

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT tuition_fee FROM Tuition WHERE tuition_code = @tuitionCode";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuitionCode", studenttuition_code);
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dr.Read();
            lblAmount.Text = dr.GetString(0);
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, but i hope help you.

Try this a bellow.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
{
  con.Open();
  string sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 tuition_fee FROM Tuition WHERE     
  tuition_code = @tuitionCode";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuitionCode", studenttuition_code);
  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    lblAmount.Text = dr["tuition_fee"].ToString();
  }
  con.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Should probably work, though you could take out the while loop if doing `TOP 1` in the select statement

Comment: And top 1 with no order by you have no way of knowing which row will come back. And if there only the possibility of 1 row then the top is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
{
   con.Open();
   string sqlQuery = "SELECT tuition_fee FROM Tuition WHERE tuition_code = @tuitionCode";
   var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuitionCode", studenttuition_code);
   var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
     lblAmount.Text = dr.GetValue; 
   }
   con.Close(); 
}
```